# How do you debug nodejs projects?

Tags: node.js, debugging, gruntjs, mean.io, angular-fullstack

For the past 16 hours or so, I've been trying to get a MEAN stack project working on my computer.

I started with the Yeoman [angular-fullstack project](https://github.com/DaftMonk/generator-angular-fullstack). But that was giving me all kinds of errors so I just gave up on it.

Then I followed some tutorials which helped me get started but didn't cover a ot of my questions.

Then I found `mean.io` which offers a full boilerplate MEAN stack project, which I followed the instructions to set up. Unfortunately, when I try to run it, I get all kinds of errors again :-(

The worst part about is, that it says NOTHING about what/where is causing the error.

**Can someone help me figure it out?** Please :-)

The latest error I'm getting is when I run `grunt`.

```
C:\Users\Imray\projects Practice\meanIO\meanApp>grunt
Running "hook" task
>> Starting hooked tasks.

Running "clean:0" (clean) task
>> 0 paths cleaned.

Running "jshint:all" (jshint) task
>> 42 files lint free.

Running "csslint:src" (csslint) task
>> 5 files lint free.

Running "concurrent:tasks" (concurrent) task
Running "watch" task
Waiting...
Running "nodemon:dev" (nodemon) task
[nodemon] v1.2.1
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching: *.*
[nodemon] starting `node --debug server.js`
debugger listening on port 5858

events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: listen EADDRINUSE
    at errnoException (net.js:904:11)
    at Server._listen2 (net.js:1042:14)
    at listen (net.js:1064:10)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1138:5)
    at ExpressEngine.beginBootstrap (C:\Users\Imray\projects Practice\meanIO\meanApp\node_modules\meanio\lib\core_modules\server\E
xpressEngine.js:123:14)
    at Meanio.serveWithDb (C:\Users\Imray\projects Practice\meanIO\meanApp\node_modules\meanio\lib\core_modules\server\index.js:14
:10)
    at Consumer.Dependable.runAction (C:\Users\Imray\projects Practice\meanIO\meanApp\node_modules\meanio\node_modules\lazy-depend
able\index.js:72:22)
    at Consumer.Dependable.fire (C:\Users\Imray\projects Practice\meanIO\meanApp\node_modules\meanio\node_modules\lazy-dependable\
index.js:69:53)
    at Consumer.onResolved (C:\Users\Imray\projects Practice\meanIO\meanApp\node_modules\meanio\node_modules\lazy-dependable\index
.js:119:8)
    at Consumer.Dependable.resolve (C:\Users\Imray\projects Practice\meanIO\meanApp\node_modules\meanio\node_modules\lazy-dependab
le\index.js:55:10)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem went away after I restarted my computer. Not sure why, but I'll take it.

Answer (score 2):

According to your output you have `Error: listen EADDRINUSE`.
It means that you already have running process on this port.

Try to investigate which process uses this port by typing:

```
sudo lsof -n -i4TCP:$PORT_NUMBER | grep LISTEN
```

Kill that process and restart your application.
If you need that process, change your application port.

Comment: I'm on Windows, so I used `resmon` to see if `5858` is being used and it's not

Answer (score 0):

EADDRINUSE is a low level system error, that usually means there's something else running on the port number you're using. Try using a different port.

EDIT: Note that it may not just be the actual server who's port is invalid. It looks like your deployment script creates a debugger, and possibly other services that listen on various ports, so they might need to be changed instead.

Comment: Instead of using `grunt` as the `mean.io` docs instruct, I used `npm start` and now I get `Error: write EINVAL - cannot write to IPC channel.`. This is so frustrating

Comment: Post the gruntfile and the grunt command you're supposed to use.

Comment: The [docs](http://learn.mean.io/) say to just use `grunt` and the gruntfile is on the [Mean.io Github repo](https://github.com/linnovate/mean/blob/master/Gruntfile.js)

Comment: Where in the `mean.io` starter app is the port defined?

Comment: So, that gruntfile sets the NODE_ENV to 'test' on line 103. Then, when it initializes the server in https://github.com/linnovate/mean/blob/master/server.js  it should be using this file  https://github.com/linnovate/mean/blob/master/config/env/test.js  to set the port

Comment: If I were you, I would put a console.log() right before  the code calls mean.serve() on line 48 in server.js, to see if even gets to that point. If it does, then its for sure throwing an error out when creating an instance of the application, else it might be something else.

Comment: I put `console.log("It got here")` and it got there. Do you think uninstalling and reinstalling Node would help?

Comment: Maybe, but unlikely, only as a last resort. Did the script throw the error right afte the console.log? Instead of "it got here", I would console.log(config.http.port) in that same place, and then in /config/env/test.js, change http.port from 3001 to 9001.  Then start your app, that console.log should now be printing out 9001, and see if the server is still throwing that error.

Comment: I put the `console.log` inside the callback function ` mean.serve({ workerid: workerId /* more options placeholder*/ }, function (app) {.....` and it doesn't even print. The error must happen before the callback is called. So the problem must be in `mean.serve`...

Comment: Right, you should log the port before mean.serve() to see what port it's initializing, and then change it.